# efficent truncate method in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to sort my table in this manner.
This is the current state of my table:

[image]

And this would be the outcome:

[image]

So basically in pseudo code it's:

```
IF SAME STRING IN "tag" COLUMN THEN add both "power"
```

Can anyone suggest an efficient way to achieve this if any?

Comment: Do you want to do this one time only, as part of a redesign of the table structure, or do you want to do it on a regular basis?

Comment: @Hammerite this will be in a cron job every 1 hour

Comment: There are certainly ways to do what you want, but they'd probably be somewhat involved. It is worth asking why you want to do it - what are you gaining out of having only one row for each "tag"? If the answer is that you want all of the quantities for each "tag" to be contained in only one row, then you would be better off applying a unique constraint to the "tag" column and carrying out updates/inserts as needed rather than just inserting whenever a new quantity is to be added.

Comment: @Hammerite i'm familiar with UPDATE and all, but this is what i need. i have to do this every hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new table called `t1_temp` with the exact same structure as your original table called `t1`.  The following should get the job done:

`TRUNCATE t1_temp; INSERT INTO t1_temp (id, power, tag) VALUES (SELECT id, SUM(power), tag FROM t1 GROUP BY tag); RENAME TABLE t1 TO t1_temp2, t1_temp TO t1, t1_temp2 TO t1_temp`

---

However, I will recommend that you try to modify your insert statement. Create a unique index on `tag` and then use something like the following (assuming that `id` is auto-increment)

`INSERT INTO t1 (power, tag) VALUES (3, 'option1') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE power = power + 3`

Answer (score 7):

```
select id, sum(power), tag from YourTabeName group by tag
```

If you need to query from it I would just make it a view.

Comment: and then DELETE * and while result INSERT ?

Comment: i guess you need a second table which is empty at the begginning, then fill it up with shaded2's query, truncate the original table, copy the second table content into the original table and eventually truncate second table.

Comment: you lost me, I would not delete anything. I would keep the original table intact, and make a view using the above query that you can call from when needed just like a table.

Comment: or dalen's suggestion works too if the new table must have the same name as the original. If not a view would be perfect because you only have to define it once. No crons necessary.

Comment: @Shaded2 I want to permanently make the desired effect on the same table

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've already solved this is another approach

```
update your_table as t1
inner join 
(select tag,sum(power) as power from your_table group by tag) as t2
set t1.power = t2.power
where t1.tag = t2.tag


alter ignore table your_table add unique index i (tag);
```